# What were the military men doing behind Donald Trump when he began his speech?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, military, inauguration

Shortly after Trump was sworn in and began giving his speech there was a group of military men that lined up in formation behind him. They stood there for a short time before walking back.

What were they doing? Was this a scheduled part of the ceremony, or was it some mixup?

Comment: I literally just watched that less than a minute ago (recorded video) and thought the exact same thing.

Comment: You can't tell on the video, but it was starting to rain, so I imagine it had something to do with that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They were delivering umbrellas. It began to rain before Trump was sworn in. It worsened as the event continued. In the image, you can see one of them coming down the stairs with an umbrella in each hand.

[image: Picture of Trump showing man in background]

Video can be seen here: http://www.cnn.com/2017/01/20/politics/trump-inaugural-address/index.html

Comment: There was one officer that came down with an umbrella, and it can't bee seen if he left with it because the camera cut to Former President Obama. The Question may be reffering to the gathering of officers after he went back upstairs. With the assortment of the branches represented, that may have been the Presidents Football team.